# What is the best visual studio version to work with apache cordova?

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova

Hello guys im new on cordova, i want to learn making an android apps using it. My friend suggest me to build the app with visual studio integrated with cordova using visual studio 2015 enterprise, he told me that visual studio 2015 is much better than visual studio 2017 because of more stable.

But im still in doubt which version should i use?

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many software (including Visual Studio), using an older version is a very good idea. For Visual Studio, I recommend not using 2017 because new versions of Visual Studio is usually not that stable and you should definitely use an older version.
Also, Visual Studio 2015 is on the [Official Microsoft tutorial for installing Apache Cordova](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/) (see the screenshot on the page) so I guess Visual Studio 2015 is the recommended version for it.
Also, when it comes to which version of VS 2015 to use, community and professional and enterprise isn't much different from each other. For the most part, community is enough for almost all development. VS 2015 Professional and Enterprise provide extra features that for the most part is not needed. 
If you want to learn more about the difference between these two, check out these websites:
 1. https://web.archive.org/web/20161015120425/https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/ (Microsoft already deleted VS 2015 comparison from its website and "https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/" now leads to the comparison of VS 2017 so this is a historical version of the website).

 2. https://www.microway.com.au/microsoft/visual-studio-2015-compare-editions.php#Fragment_Title

Comment: thanks for the reply,
like what u said, my lecture said VS 2015 is the best to choose...
and 1 more question,
there which one is better? community/profesional/enterprise?

Comment: I have added an explanation for which version of VS 2015 to use in the original answer.